# Excel VBA code to subtract

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following table

```
Bills Amount Paid

Food  $100    No

Gas   $200    Yes

Car   $300    Yes

Total $600

Total left to pay: $400
```

And I have the following code

```
Sub Bills()

    Range("C2").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell = "Yes" Then Range("B6") = Range("B5") - ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

But it only subtracts the first "Yes" and when I change another to "Yes" i do not see were is getting the new amount to subtract it from. what am I missing?

Goal: Whenever I have paid a bill and come here and select "Yes" and run the code it will subtract it from the total and show me how much I still have left to pay on bills.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: Don't use VBA where it is not necessary. You can simply solve this without a macro with the excel function `SUMIF`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Column B is the "Amount" Column and Column C is the "Paid" column, simply use the formula in the cell for "left to pay"

```
=SUMIF(C2:C4,"=NO",B2:B4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `Formula` to evaluate the `Column` Paid:

```
=SUMIF(C2:C4;"No";B2:B4)
```